# SSH Browser Rendering Stuck on Private Key (Cloudflare)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have sucessfully tunnel a SSH over Cloudflared but it keep asking for private key instead password only like tutorial, so i found this solution for help

[image: Imgur]

*https://community.cloudflare.com/t/second-app-with-ssh-browser-rendering-asks-for-private-key/513983*

Answer (score 0):

To fix that we need to set
`PasswordAuthentication no` in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`